# Why do my source files have <<<< and >>>> in them?

Tags: php, mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm using TortoiseHG with our repository, I have huge problem all the files in my repository looks like this AND if I want to upload that folder to my LAMP server it won't work, as the code is messed up:

```
<<<<<<< local
<?
require '../dbconnect.php';
require '../includes/functions.php';
require '../includes/adminfunctions.php';

$sql = "Delete from bl_researcher Where ID=6";
$result = mysql_query ($sql) or die(mysql_error());
=======
<?
require '../dbconnect.php';
require '../includes/functions.php';
require '../includes/adminfunctions.php';

$sql = "Delete from bl_researcher Where ID=6";
$result = mysql_query ($sql) or die(mysql_error());
>>>>>>> other
?>
```

Comment: That's a conflicted file. Someone else committed a change to the file after you got the latest version, then you made your changes to the old version.

Comment: TortoiseHG should have an "edit conflicts" option somewhere in the menu.. try that.

Answer (score 1):

choose which code does what it is expected and when you make a push and there are conflicts you can right-click on that the file...**show diff from base** and you can choose which code block is the working/updated one...and when done you mark as **resolved** some code can be highlighted with blue...no problem ( can be the exact same thing ), the **red** ones you should be worried